# Google Drive - Accessing file tree entries and their type

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

How does one retrieve the file tree for a google drive account using the Google Drive iOS API?

I am able to access the list of files from what I have read on the developer site for Google Drive and through the sample apps, but I am not sure how one gets the file tree and how to distinguish if an entry is a folder or file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `mimeType` property of the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) to distinguish between files and folders. Folders will list `application/vnd.google-apps.folder` as their MIME type:

https://developers.google.com/drive/folder

You can use the `Parents` collection to list the parents of a file and build a tree. Remember that a file can have multiple parents, i.e. be included in multiple folders:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents/list

Comment: Thanks. Could you please take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189073/incorrect-file-tree-google-drive-api

Comment: Does the Google Drive API have a helper method to retrieve a list of files, rather than ChildRefs, for a given folderID?