# Incorrect File Tree Google Drive API

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am initializing a `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` with

```
[[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive...
```

And I am requesting the file list:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];

[self.driveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                          GTLDriveFileList *fileList,
                                                          NSError *error) {
}];
```

This returns all the files from the linked Drive account. For some reason the file changes made to the Drive folder e.g. Putting all the files into a folder, are not being updated no the device linked to the Drive service. Refetching the file list is not showing the updated list, the single folder now containing the files.

Is this a Drive bug or do I have configure the request differently?

Comment: You are sending a query to retrieve all files in Drive and that's what you are getting. If you want to limit results to a single folder or other criteria, check https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

Comment: If I ask for the childList of a folder I get GTLDriveChildReferences back. How do I then determine the GTLDriveFile objects from these references? I would like to get the contents of a folder and then be able to determine folder and file between the items.

Comment: Each Children resource includes the unique id of the file it references: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children

Comment: Thanks. Is there a method to fetch the file along with the child? Or must the ChildList be iterated and its file metadata be downloaded using the fileID? I would like to just show a tableview with the items for a particular folder and in the didSelectTableViewCell I want to detect a file or a folder to handle each appropriately. I guess my question is if there is a method to get a fileList for a folder, rather than the children references?

Comment: You should send a files.list request with a query parameter like "?q='1234567' in parents" (where '1234567' is the folder id) to retrieve all files in that folder. Read https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters for more details